# Auto update when onSubmit with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that post/get data from json. However when I add a comment, the latest comment that I added did not append automatically, but it will show if i refresh or reinstate the values.

Here's the code that handles my comments

```js
handleCommentChange(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  }

  handleComment(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var callback = console.log('lol');
    Request.post('http://localhost:3000/api/comments')
           .send({
            idComment: this.state.id,
            author: this.state.name,
            text: this.state.text
          })
           .end(callback)
           this.ReturnComment();

    var newItem = {
      id: Date.now(),
      author: this.state.name,
      text: this.state.text
    };
    // this.setState((prevState) => ({
    //   items: prevState.items.concat(newItem),
    //   text: ""
    // }));
    this.setState({
      text: ""
    });
  }



  ReturnComment(){
    var urlComment = "http://localhost:3000/api/comments";
    Request.get(urlComment)
            .then((i) => {this.setState({commentBody: i})});
  }
```

And this is the component that uses those functions

```js
export default React.createClass ({

  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <h1>Comments <small>on {this.props.pokeName}</small></h1>
        <div className="commentsSection">
          <div>
            <div>
                {this.props.commentBody.body
                  .filter((objComment) => {return objComment.author === this.props.pokeName})
                  .map((i) => {return (
                                <div className="itemComment">
                                  <p className="no-margin">"{i.text}"</p>
                                  <p className="right">-{i.id}</p>
                                </div>)
                              })
                }
                 {this.props.items.map(item => (
                    <div className="itemComment">
                      <p className="no-margin" key={item.id}>"{item.text}"</p>
                      <p className="right">-{item.id}</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
                 
          </div>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleComment}>
          <textarea className="textarea" onChange={this.props.onChange} value={this.props.text} rows="4"/>
          <button className="btn btn-default">Comment</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because, inside `handleComment`, you are calling `this.ReturnComment()` without waiting for the POST API to complete.

So GET API fetches the same old data. But as you said if you refresh the page, you will get the new data from API.

So you can do it like this:

```
  handleComment(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var callback = console.log('lol');
    Request.post('http://localhost:3000/api/comments')
      .send({
        idComment: this.state.id,
        author: this.state.name,
        text: this.state.text
      })
      .then(() => this.ReturnComment())
      .end(callback)

    // ... rest of the things
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, it works however i got this error `Uncaught TypeError: _superagent2.default.post(...).send(...).then(...).end is not a function(…)`

Comment: nevermind, i just removed `.end()` and the error is gone. thanks.